# Show multiple route in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a map related project in Windows phone 8. I can show route from my location to destination but i want to show multiple route. For example, A to B there will be 2 route.
Thanks

Comment: Help my Answer? You get the solution? if yes please select as Answered, if not tell us if we can help you. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using [Maps directions task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from the Windows Phone SDK, you cant set this possiblity because its a standalone method that call the maps to calculate from A to B.

If you want to a better Map integration I suggest to look to [HERE Maps Api](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html). Its more powerful.

https://developer.here.com/documents